# Authentication to SalesForce Marketing Cloud API through Springboot

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are trying to authenticate to SalesForce Marketing Cloud through springboot security oauth2. By postman we can get an authorization token, but not from spring where we are receiving the error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Make sure that the client ID and client secret are valid and that the following parameters are not empty or null: client ID, client secret, and grant type.",
    "error_uri": "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs"
}
```

We could recreate the error in postman if we change the body request like this - see `clientId`:

```
{
 "grant_type": "client_credentials",
 "clientId": "{{SF_clientId}}",
 "client_secret": "{{SF_clientSecret}}",
 "account_id": "{{SF_accountId}}"
}
```

What we think that is happen is spring framework is adding `clientId` instead `client_id` in authorization request body.

We are using a FeignClient and this is our configuration class:

```
public class SalesForceConfiguration {

    @Value("${security.oauth2.salesforce.accessTokenUri}")
    protected String accessTokenUri;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.salesforce.clientId}")
    protected String clientId;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.salesforce.clientSecret}")
    protected String clientSecret;
    
    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.FULL;
    }

    @Bean
    ErrorDecoder errorDecoder() {return new SalesforceErrorDecoder();}

    @Bean
    RequestInterceptor oauth2FeignRequestInterceptor() {
        return new SalesforceAuthenticationFeignRequestInterceptor(oAuth2ClientContext(),
                oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails(),
                null);
    }
    @Bean
    OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails() {
        final BaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resourceDetails = baseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
        resourceDetails.setClientId(clientId);
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        return resourceDetails;
    }

    private BaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails baseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails() {
        return new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    }

    OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext() {
        return new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();
    }
}
```

Does anyone already had the same problem and could share some advices?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Setting the authentication scheme to form seems to do the trick:

```
@Bean
OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails() {
  final BaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resourceDetails = baseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails();
  resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
  resourceDetails.setClientId(clientId);
  resourceDetails.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
  resourceDetails.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
  return resourceDetails;
}
```